# How to use Protobuf generated classes as types with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Apologies if this is rudimentary but I'm new to TypeScript and was wondering... let's say I generate a Protobuf `.js` file called

```
request_pb.js
```

And I'd like to incorporate one of the generated classes as a TypeScript type when passing in a value e.g. something akin to...

```js
const req = require('../build/gen/request_pb');

/**
 * check if incoming request is valid
 * @param data
 */
function validateRequest(data: req.Request) { // TODO: how to include type information?
    return data.hasStartDateEt() && data.hasEndDateEt();
}
```

I'm currently getting

> "Cannot find namespace 'req'"

What does this mean exactly and what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated the TypeScript definition files into the same build directory using

```
$ protoc --proto_path=schemas --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:build/gen --ts_out=build/gen schemas/*.proto schemas/enums/*.proto
```

and the `ts-protoc-gen` package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-protoc-gen).

I was then able to import the types using

```js
import account_statement_req from '../build/gen/account_statement_request_pb';
```